# Scroll not working on my forms container when inside flex:1 container

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I have a container with a defined height of 100vh and inside it I have a header with a fixed height and a content container with flex:1 to fill the rest of the height. Inside the content container I have a sidenav and a content container. Inside the content container I have a forms with flex:1 to fill everything left and a buttons container below with a fixed height. I have overflow: scroll on my forms but somehow its not working and the whole page is getting scroll instead

Codepen Example:

https://codepen.io/githubtiagomarques/pen/qBgOmgq

I want the page to stay at 100vh and the forms to get scroll insstead.

`.forms{ overflow-y: scroll; flex: 1 !important; }`

Codepen Example: https://codepen.io/githubtiagomarques/pen/qBgOmgq

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your forms-container is nested inside of the nav-content.

nav-content and forms-container both have a height of 100%, which overflow-y isn't respecting, it needs a hard defined unit in order to set the scroll boundaries. Changing the height in your css to 400px (to match the height of your container) gives you overflow behaviour that you're missing.

```
.forms-container{
  height: 400px; /* This can't be 100% for the overflow to work */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

However this doesn't get you what you described, which is a full screen container with the scrolling sections. So here are some different additions.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 16px); /* This is full screen minus the margin of your heading (which is 16px) */
  border: solid 5px black;
}

.forms-container {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px - 100px); /* This is full screen minus the margin of your heading and the height of your buttons div */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.section {
  height: 150px; /* I made this larger as the supplied size isn't big enough to scroll */ 
}
```

There are plenty of other responsive things to take into account, which I won't go into here but this should help get further along your way. I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm aware that defining the height like that might fixz the probllem, but I wanted to make it as dynamic as possible, in a way that if I somehow need to change my header's height I won't need to change anything else